# How to bind console.log to "l" in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

main.js has this code

```
window.l = function () { }
try {
  window.l = console.log.bind(console)
} catch (e) { }
```

which works in non-Vue apps. However, when calling

```
l("test")
```

from a Vue action/method, it complains it isn't defined.

How can that work?

Reasoning: need to output some debugging data, with as less typing as possible.

Comment: Where did you define `window.l`?

Comment: in main.js
Should it be somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to add global-level functionalities to Vue, you should generally use **mixins** or **plugins**.

For the next examples, I assume you are using **vue-cli** with the complete **webpack** template. Moreover, we will use `App.vue` as a practical reference, but you can apply the same principles to other components...

---

## Mixins

Create a mixin named `log.js` (in a `mixins` folder) with the following code:

```
export default {
  methods: {
    l (...args) { // rest parameters
      console.log(...args) // spread operator
    }
  }
}
```

Open `App.vue`, import your mixin and use it:

```
<script>
  import log from './mixins/log'

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    mixins: [log],
    created () {
      this.l('Foo', 'Bar') // Foo Bar
    }
  }
</script>
```

---

## Plugins

Create a plugin named `log.js` (in a `plugins` folder) with the following code:

```
export default {
  install (Vue, options) {
    Vue.prototype.$l = console.log.bind(console)
    Vue.l = console.log.bind(console)
  }
}
```

Open your `main.js` and declare your global plugin:

```
import log from './plugins/log'
Vue.use(log)
```

Open `App.vue`, import `Vue` and use your plugin:

```
<script>
  import Vue from 'vue'

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    created () {
      this.$l('Foo') // Foo
      Vue.l('Bar') // Bar
    }
  }
</script>
```

---

You might say: "Hey, why should I have to write `this` or `Vue`? I just wanna write `l`, that's all!". Well... This is actually how Vue has been designed. In order to provide global functionalities (shared by all components), you have to add **static properties** to the `Vue` object or **prototype properties** (`Vue.prototype`) that are accessible through `this` in `Vue` instances.

---

**EDIT**

I have just thought about an alternative solution...

You can edit your `index.html` to add this:

```
<script>
  var l = console.log.bind(console)
</script>
```

Then, to avoid ESLint errors, you should also edit your `.eslintrc.js` file to reference your new global variable:

```
globals: {
  l: true
}
```

The file looks like this:

```
// http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  parserOptions: {
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  globals: {
    l: true
  },
  env: {
    browser: true,
  },
  // https://github.com/feross/standard/blob/master/RULES.md#javascript-standard-style
  extends: 'standard',
  // required to lint *.vue files
  plugins: [
    'html'
  ],
  // add your custom rules here
  'rules': {
    // allow paren-less arrow functions
    'arrow-parens': 0,
    // allow async-await
    'generator-star-spacing': 0,
    // allow debugger during development
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 2 : 0
  }
}
```

**Restart your dev server.** Now you should be able to use `l` in your code:

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'app',
    created () {
      l('It works!')
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer, including "Hey, why should I have to write this or Vue?" (you read my mind), and the alternative solution (great!). You rock!

Answer (score 1):

Assign console.log like this.

```
window.l=console.log;
```

Comment: using 
l('test') in another Vue file gives 
Uncaught ReferenceError: l is not defined
    at eval (webpack-internal:///67:4)
    at Object.<anonymous> (

Even the long form (although we don't want that) gives Uncaught TypeError: window.l is not a function

Comment: I put this in public/index.html and restarted the server and it worked in a vue file.